# PHP - Check if array keys matches an array of keys

Tags: php

I have the following array:

```php
"origem_fornecedor" => array:5 [▼
  "A" => 50
  "B" => 70
  "C" => 50
  "D" => 85
  "E" => 50
]
```

And I need to check if the keys present in that array matches the values present in this constant:

```php
const NIVEIS = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
```

Arrays that should fail this test:

```php
"origem_fornecedor" => array:2 [▼
  "A" => 50
  "B" => 70
]
```

```php
"origem_fornecedor" => array:7 [▼
  "A" => 50
  "B" => 70
  "C" => 50
  "D" => 85
  "E" => 50
  "F" => 95
  "G" => 10
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ( array_keys($origem_fornecedor) == NIVEIS ) echo "Ok"; else echo "KO";
```

PS : What's this syntax : "origem_fornecedor" ?

Comment: Can't believe I couldn't solve that myself, thank you so much for your help!

The syntax is from Laravel's `dd();`